# Can't call JavaScript function - ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

This is actually an Adobe AIR app, but since the problem I'm having is with very basic JavaScript, I thought I should put it here.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>KM Ciclo de Servicio</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/ciclo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changefield()
{
    #('#ciclo').append('ASD');
}
</script>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<div id="topMenu">
    <button class="menuItem" id="new" title="Nuevo"><img src="images/new.png" alt="Nuevo"/></button>
    <button class="menuItem" id="save" title="Guardar"><img src="images/save.png" alt="Guardar"/></button>
    <button class="menuItem" id="open" title="Abrir"><img src="images/open.png" alt="Abrir"/></button>
    <input type="text" value="Momento cambiado" onkeypress="changefield()"/>
        <div style="display: inline-block; float: right;">
        Nuevo:
        <button class="menuItem" id="momento">Momento</button>
        <button class="menuItem" id="atributo">Atributo</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" align="center">
    <div id="ciclo"></div>
</div>
<script src="script/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the function I'm trying to call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changefield()
{
    #('#ciclo').append('ASD');
}
</script>
```

However, my terminal tells me there's an error on `line 20`, which is:

```
<input type="text" value="Momento cambiado" onkeypress="changefield()"/>
```

The error says:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: changefield
>   onkeypress at app:/index.html : 19

I have checked some tutorials on JavaScript functions to make sure (including the one at w3schools), and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. I am calling the function exactly how these tutorials suggest I do so.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper syntax is this:

```
function changefield()
{
    $('#ciclo').append('ASD');
}
```

This was a javascript syntax error:

```
#('#ciclo').append('ASD');
```

which caused the changefield function to not be defined.

Comment: You're right! Can't believe I made a typo like that in the code haha. Well, thanks for pointing it out, it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Problem might be that jQuery creates `$` variable, not `#`

```
function changefield()
{
    $('#ciclo').append('ASD');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `#` should be `$`

```
function changefield() {
    $('#ciclo').append('ASD');
}
```

This `SyntaxError` was causing the `changefield` function to not be created so the inline `onkeypress` couldn't find it.

Comment: Damn but your name is annoying, and essentially impossible to directly respond to on any device other than desktop/laptop.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I'm a troublemaker. Sorry.

Comment: Not trouble, just deliberately exclusionary, which somewhat runs counter to the point. Whatever.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Deliberately exclusionary? Wow, that sure sounds like trouble to me. I guess I better change it when StackOverflow lets me in 27 days. Till then, we're stuck. :(

Comment: Actually no, you can copy your profile from other SE sites to get around that particular hurdle.

Comment: @DaveNewton: u hackr! ;) I'll give it a shot later on.